# Best method to detect structure in the residuals?

Tags: r, matlab, residuals, scipy

I need to fit an expression to a large number of datasets. In most, the fit is good; but for some, it is not (residuals have a clear structure). Variance in the data differs between the datasets, so the standard goodness-of-fit methods (reduced chi-square, etc) don't seem to help me tell a reasonable but noisy fit from a wrong fit. Visual inspection of all the fits is not an option.

I am using an ad-hoc metric constructed as follows (Python code below): 
(1) "fit" the residuals by local smoothing
(2) sum the differences between the smoothing line and the abscissa
(3) rescale to account for the number of datapoints.

The value for the metric is substantially greater for structured residuals (with a large area between the abscissa and the line approximating the residuals) vs unstructured residuals (where the residuals just vary around 0).

**So this works but is definitely ad-hoc. Is there a better way?**

Python or R are preferred; MATLAB is OK. "Theoretical" suggestions are welcome as well.

Importantly, this is not a situation where there are alternative models; there is only one model. I want to flag any "structured" disagreements with it.

Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

np.random.seed(9001)
x = np.linspace(1,100,200); 

# simulated data
def fsigm(x,a,b,k): return k+((1-k)/(1+(a/x)**b))
noise = np.random.randn(len(x))/30
y = fsigm(x,30,-3,0.1) + noise

# a poorly-fitting model
def flin(x,a,b): return a*x+b
(popt,pcov) = sp.optimize.curve_fit(flin,x,y)

# noise == residuals from a perfect fit

# residuals with a lot of structure 
res = y - flin(x,*popt)
#print(np.var(res))

# randomized residuals, stand for residuals from a good fit
# different structure, same variance
res_rand = res.copy()
np.random.shuffle(res_rand)
```

I am defining an ad-hoc metric which is, roughly, a normalized area between a smoothing curve and the abscissa:

```
# (any local smoother here)
def csmooth(y, w):
    return np.convolve(y, np.ones(w)/w, mode='same')

noise_smoothed = csmooth(noise, 50)
res_smoothed = csmooth(res, 50)
res_rand_smoothed = csmooth(res_rand, 50)

m0 = np.sum(np.abs(noise_smoothed))/len(x)*100
m1 = np.sum(np.abs(res_smoothed))/len(x)*100
m2 = np.sum(np.abs(res_rand_smoothed))/len(x)*100

# Metric for the structured residual much greater than 
# that for the unstructured version of the residual
print("Metric for residuals:\nstructured: {:.2f}\nunstructured: {:.2f}\nperfect {:.2f}".format(m1,m2,m0))
```

Result:

```
Metric for residuals:
structured: 8.25
unstructured: 1.33
perfect 0.43
```

[image: Poor fit]
[image: Residuals and local smoothing]

Comment: R^2 of spline fit to residuals?  Seems slightly less ad-hoc than integrated area between spline and abscissa ...

Comment: @BenBolker - How would using r^2 help me differentiate between a good fit to a spline that is far away from the abscissa (i.e. serious case of residuals with structure) and a good fit to a spline which is coincident with the abscissa? (no structure) Am I missing something here?

Comment: well, if you scale the residuals so they have variance 1 (e.g. `residuals(x)/summary(x)$sigma` for a linear regression fit), then you've scaled away "distance from the abscissa".

Comment: OK, I can see that a computable example will be useful after all. Will post an example shortly.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What kind of data are you working with? Is it cross sectional, time series, something else?

Comment: @RichardHardy - Thanks! The data is time series (instrument readings over time, equally spaced). I need to deal with both individual measurements and averages of two or three measurements per timepoint.

Comment: Consider adding a `time-series` tag then. In time series models it is common to look for autocorrelations in the residuals or squared residuals, so that is one kind of structure you could consider.

Comment: @RichardHardy - I don't have any reason to expect periodicity in these datasets; they are not particularly "timeseries-like".